# Pop-up text over table heading: make <SPAN> display centered and above <TH>

Tags: html, css, html-table

The headings of my table are abbreviated dates.  I want to pop up the full date directly above the abbreviated date when I hover over the abbreviated date.

Here is an example `<th>`:

```
<th class="dateHeading">Jun 01<span class="fullDate">Wednesday (06-01-2016)</span></th>
```

I'm using the following CSS to position and display the `<span>` above the `<th>`:

```
th.dateHeading {
  word-spacing: 9999999px; /* force one word per line (stacking) */
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

th.dateHeading:hover .fullDate {
  display: block;
}

.fullDate {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #C8C8C8;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
  transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -70px);
}
```

The problem is that the `<span>` is not horizontally centered with the corresponding `<th>`. How can I center it?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7erhwwt/)

Comment: Note: If I can do this reasonably concisely *without* using transforms, that would be ideal (though not required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below should center the full date horizontally above your abbreviated date.
Add the following to your CSS:

```
th.dateHeading {
  position: relative;
}

.fullDate {
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

th,
td {
  width: 30px;
}

th.tableHeading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -20px);
}

th.dateHeading {
  word-spacing: 9999999px;
  /* force one word per line */
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: crosshair;
  position: relative;
}

th.dateHeading:hover .fullDate {
  display: block;
}

.fullDate {
  display: none;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #C8C8C8;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
  transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -70px);
}

.green {
  background-color: #388C43;
  width: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: #B22222;
  width: 20px;
}

.rowName {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tableHeading">My Table</th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 01<span class="fullDate">Wednesday (06-01-2016)</span></th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 16<span class="fullDate">Thursday (06-16-2016)</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">A</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">B</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the parent container (dateHeading) to be position: relative, and then set the date flyout (fullDate) to be position:absolute. This will position the flyout relative to it's parent.

I then specified the left: attribute of fullDate to be -100%, so it will center it.

See [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2wgsjjp/).

```
.fullDate {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #C8C8C8;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-40px;
  left: -100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `position: relative` to parent `th` and in your `span` you may remove the `width` (optional here) working with `padding`, and you have add `left` for `position:absolute`

Note that this will align the box itself and not the text inside to the shortened date

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
th,
td {
  width: 30px;
}
th.tableHeading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -20px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -20px);
}
th.dateHeading {
  word-spacing: 9999999px;
  /* force one word per line */
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: crosshair;
  position: relative
}
th.dateHeading:hover .fullDate {
  display: block;
}
.fullDate {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #C8C8C8;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 120%;
  transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -70px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -70px);
}
.green {
  background-color: #388C43;
  width: 20px;
}
.red {
  background-color: #B22222;
  width: 20px;
}
.rowName {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tableHeading">My Table</th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 01<span class="fullDate">Wednesday (06-01-2016)</span>
      </th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 16<span class="fullDate">Thursday (06-16-2016)</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">A</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">B</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your transform code, Just play with positions, check below:

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

th,
td {
  width: 30px;
}

th.tableHeading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-align: left;
 
}

th.dateHeading {
  word-spacing: 9999999px;
  /* force one word per line */
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: crosshair;
   position: relative;
}

th.dateHeading:hover .fullDate {
  display: block;
}

.fullDate {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: -33px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #C8C8C8;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.green {
  background-color: #388C43;
  width: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: #B22222;
  width: 20px;
}

.rowName {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tableHeading">My Table</th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 01<span class="fullDate">Wednesday (06-01-2016)</span></th>
      <th class="dateHeading">Jun 16<span class="fullDate">Thursday (06-16-2016)</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">A</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rowName">B</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="red">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you look closely at the div, you'll see that it is not perfectly centered. Also, your solution is not dynamic, so if the width of the div changes, it won't be centered anymore.